# Archiving a react native product takes a very very long time. Anyone able to resolve this issue?

Tags: ios, react-native

When we are trying to create an xarchive of our React Native project, it takes over 15 mins for the archive to build.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer why creating a React Native iOS archive takes so long lately, but it will things up by increasing the number of Xcode parallel build tasks:

```
defaults write com.apple.xcode PBXNumberOfParallelBuildSubtasks 4
defaults write com.apple.xcode IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks 4
```